# F# how do I create an Array/List of Structs

Tags: f#

I am very new to F#, and I'm trying to simply get an array of structs where the struct is the filename and the filecontents is an array of lines in the file. I have an error I don't really understand on the indicated line, and I haven't been able to find the correct syntax or approach to do this.

```
let readFileContents filePath = 
    File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

let makeFileStruct fileName =
    new FileContents(fileName, fileName |> readFileContents)

let fileTemplates path = 
    Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.template") 
    |> Array.map(fun x -> Path.GetFileName(x))
    |> Array.iter(fun x -> makeFileStruct(x))     <--- error: This expression was expected to have type 'unit'

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Testing getting files"
    argv.[0] 
    |> fileTemplates
    |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
    |> printfn "some stuff %s"
    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to simply get an array of structs where the struct is the filename

I don't think this is a good idea becuase in order to get the predictable memory usage of a struct you'd need some combination of a very strict filename length limit and/or a very memory-inefficient struct. Unless the struct contains an non-struct object.

> I have an error I don't really understand on the indicated line

Array.iter executes a function for each element of the array. So the inner function `makeFileStruct` would need to return a unit in order to execute it. You are looking for `Array.map` which creates an array from the outputs.